# Creating a customized message status code

Tags: php, cakephp, http-status-code-403

Im trying create a customized status code message. But im new im php and cakephp. So i need some help.

Im my FunctionsComponent i did this:

public function setStatusMsg($code, $method) {

```
    switch ($code) {

        case 200: 
        $msg = 'Some msg'; 
        break;

        case 201: 
        $msg = 'Some msg'; 
        break;

        case 202: 
        $msg = 'Some msg'; 
        break;

        case 400: 
        $msg = 'Some msg'; 
        break;

        case 401: 
        $msg = 'Some msg'; 
        break;

        case 403: 
        $msg = 'Forbidden'; 
        break;

        case 404:
        $msg = 'Some msg'; 
        break;

        case 500: 
        $msg = 'Some msg'; 
        break;
    }
    return $code;
}
```

How can i call the function component im my controller?

I tryied: $message = $this->Functions->setStatusMsg($code);

but dont works

Comment: read documentation https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want to do. If you want do error handling, you can use cakePHP error handling API. Anyway, you can do this the following way.

e.g This is your Controller

```
class YourController extends AppController {
     public $components = ['Functions'];

     public function doStuff() {
        $code = 200;
        $message = $this->Functions->setStatusMsg($code);
        //Execute your code
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But I got it. I was trying to handle the error message for all endpoints in a custom way.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my solution:
 Im my FunctionsComponent:

      public function getStatusMessage($code, $method) 
     {
         switch (true) {
             case $method == 'DELETE' && $code == 200:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'DELETE' && $code == 403:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'DELETE' && $code == 500:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'DELETE':
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'POST' && $code == 200:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'POST' && $code == 403:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'POST' && $code == 500:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'POST':
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'PUT' && $code == 200:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'PUT' && $code == 403:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method =='PUT' && $code == 500:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'PUT' && $code == 404:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'GET' && $code == 200:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'GET' && $code == 403:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method == 'GET' && $code == 500:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             case $method =='GET':
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
             default:
                 $msg = 'Some message.';
                 break;
         }
         return $msg;
     }

Im my controller:

 public function index(){
  $method = $this->request->Method();
    //my code..
  if(sucess){
    $this->setResponse($this->response->withStatus(200));
    $message = $this->Functions->getStatusMessage(200, $method);
 } else {
  $this->setResponse($this->response->withStatus(403));
  $message = $this->Functions->getStatusMessage(403, $method);
```